# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tag_name'

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, pytest, python-3.9

Selecting the value from the dropdown which has a select tag in Selenium. However, I am getting the following error while selecting the value from the dropdown.

Her is my Code:

```
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
    import time
    from Pages.BasePage import Common
    from configration.config import Data
    
    
    class OrderCycle(Common):
        # By Locator
        
        US_State = (By.XPATH, "//option[@value='AL']")
       
    
        # Constructor of the page class
    
        def __init__(self, driver):
            # super().__init__(driver)
            self.driver = driver
            self.driver.get(Data.Base_url)
        # Page Action for Order cycle
    
      
        # Select the state from the Dropdown.
        def select_state(self):
            self.do_click(self.US_State), Select(self.US_State).select_by_visible_text("Alabama")
```

**Actual Result:**

```
FAILED Test/test_CartItem.py::TestOrder::test_select_product[chrome] - AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tag_name'
FAILED Test/test_CartItem.py::TestOrder::test_select_product[firefox] - AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tag_name'
```

Comment: Which library are using for `Common`?

Comment: Maximilian Peters: This is not a library, This is my class name that Inherited in OrderCylce class.   

Here is the code: 

class Common:

    def __int__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def do_click(self, by_locator):
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator)).click()

    def do_send_keys(self, by_locator, text):
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator)).send_keys(text)

Comment: Your code does not contain the failing test. Please consider providing a [mcve] reproducing the error. Most probably an unnecessary comma was placed somewhere in a return statement.

Comment: Can you add all the code to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Removing the Brackets and it worked now. US_State = By.XPATH, "//option[@value='AL']"